# How do I make a notepad executable?

Tags: notepad

I'm having trouble changing my notepad file into an executable, so that it runs whatever it contains. On a side note, is there any basic way of telling notepad to run a program/open a saved file (i.e. run:"file location")? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: This would be a better fit on Super User.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly are you referring to? are you trying to create a batch file that opens a specified program?

if this is the case, change the file extension of the notepad file to .bat

Comment: Hi, sorry for being vague. I'd like to open a file using an executable i.e. instead of opening a Word document I'd click on the notepad executable which opens the Word document. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: you mean you want to be able to doubleclick on a file, which in turn will open a different file stored elsewhere on your computer?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.

Comment: I have drawn it out for you [<Screenshot>](http://i.imgur.com/YJDgrAi.png)

Comment: cd changes the "active directory"
start executes the given file. note that the file you are trying to start has to be in the active directory. for instance if you had a file called test.rtf in your C:\ folder you can do

cd c:\
start test.rtf

Comment: Yes, it works just like you explained, so thank you! I'm sure I can look up how to change from .bat to .exe now, unless you know how to do that off the top of your head too?

Comment: a .exe (executable) is a file with code that is to be compiled and executed. a .bat (batch) file does not need to be compiled, but if you desire to turn it into a .exe you can use any converter you can find. for example: [this one](http://download.cnet.com/Bat-To-Exe-Converter-Portable/3000-2069_4-10555897.html) If i answered your question correctly please press the button on the left of my answer.